# Encoding - Problems creating JSON using an Unicode Object in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I've got some real problems to encode/decode strings to a specific charset (UTF-8).

My Unicode Object is:

```
>> u'Valor Econ\xf4mico - Opini\xe3o'
```

When I call print from python it returns:

```
>> Valor Econômico - Opinião
```

When I call .encode("utf-8") from my unicode object to write it to a JSON it returns:

```
>> 'Valor Econ\xc3\xb4mico - Opini\xc3\xa3o'
```

What am I doing wrong? What exactly is print() doing that I'm not?

Obs: I'm creating this unicode object from a line of a file.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(path, 'r') as local_file:
    for line in local_file:
        obj = unicode((line.replace(codecs.BOM_UTF8, '')).replace('\n', ''), 'utf-8')
```

Comment: why do you need to encode it to write it to json?

Comment: the json module already supports unicode automatically

Comment: Using the standard json module, calling json.dumps(your_string) works just fine. The application that will decode this JSON is UTF-8 compliant?

Comment: That is just the `repr` output, when you `print 'Valor Econ\xc3\xb4mico - Opini\xc3\xa3o'.encode("utf-8")` it will be `Valor Econômico - Opinião
`

Comment: I was trying to create a file where every line is a json. However, my goal is to write "Valor Econômico - Opinião" on this file, not "u'Valor Econ\xf4mico - Opini\xe3o'. That's why I tried to encode it. I'm kind of lost.
My json is being created by a flag " -t json -o b.json " when I'm running a scrapy spider script

Comment: Generally when JSON is sent over the internet, it is converted to ascii characters with unicode characters escaped with \uXXXX for compatibility. There's an option in dumps `json.dumps(text,ensure_ascii=False)`, but that's probably not what you want to do here. Why does the text in the file need to be JSON?

Comment: @csunday95: This file will be read by another application later.

Comment: @csunday95: I understand, so the correct way of doing it should be, save it as 'Valor Econ\xc3\xb4mico - Opini\xc3\xa3o' and leave the another application to treat it?

Answer (score 1):

`Valor Econ\xc3\xb4mico - Opini\xc3\xa3o` is the UTF-8 representation prepared for a non-UTF-8 terminal, probably in the interactive shell. If you were to write this to a file (`open("myfile", "wb").write("Valor Econ\xc3\xb4mico - Opini\xc3\xa3o"`) then you'd have a valid UTF-8 file.

To create Unicode strings from a file, you can use automatic decoding in the io module (`Codecs.open()` is being deprecated). BOMs will be removed automatically:

```
import io
with io.open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as local_file:
    for line in local_file:
        unicode_obj = line.strip()
```

When it comes to creating a JSON response, use the result from `json.dumps(my_object)`. It will return an str with all non-ASCII chars encoded using Unicode codepoints.